# How to append a list with raw_input in Python and print min and max values

Tags: python, list, max, min, raw-input

I am trying to build a list with raw inputs.

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    #edge cases
    if inp == "done" : break
    if len(inp) < 1 : break

    #building list 
    try:
        num_list = []
        num = int(inp)
        num_list.append(num)
    except:
        print "Please enter a number."
        continue

    #max and min functions
    high = max(num_list)
    low = min(num_list)

#print results 
print "The highest number: ", high
print "The lowest number: ", low

print "Done!"
```

At the moment it seems to only save one of the inputs at a time and therefore the the last raw input is printed as both the max and min.

Any ideas? I am new to Python and could use some direction. So far I have been unable to find the answer in StackOverflow or in the Python documentation. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should declare and initialize the `num_list` outside the while loop.

Comment: You need to put "num_list = []" before the while loop. If you have "num_list = []" inside the while loop, all the previously entered values are deleted on each iteration of the loop

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Thanks to crs17 for the explanation. Things are working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you keep erasing the list with each iteration.  Put `num_list = []` outside the `while` loop:

```
num_list = []
while True:
    ...
```

You should also put these two lines:

```
high = max(num_list)
low = min(num_list)
```

outside the loop.  There is no reason to keep executing them over and over again.